# Change response code in javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet

Tags: java, http, servlets, httpresponse, http-response-codes

In an implementation of `javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet` an exception is thrown in a method. So the HTTP response code is `500`.

Is it somehow possible to set the response code to something else? Or is it every time `500` whenever an exception occurs?

Comment: Sure. Just catch the Exception and use `HttpServletRespons#setStatus()` - see http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#setStatus%28int%29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check the precondition or catch the exception and set the desired response status via [`HttpServletResponse#setStatus()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#setStatus-int-) or [`HttpServletResponse#sendError()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#sendError-int-), depending on the nature of the status code (4nn/5nn == error).

The way how your question is formulated suggests that it's in your situation not possible to perform a simple preconditional check using e.g. an `if` statement like below basic example:

```
if (foo != null) { 
    processFoo(request, response, foo);
}
else {
    response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST);
}
```

Apparently it's a 3rd party servlet or so. In that case, create a [servlet filter](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlet-filters/info) which does below job in `Filter#doFilter()` method and map it to the desired servlet:

```
try {
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
catch (ServletException e) {
    if (e.getRootCause() instanceof IllegalArgumentException) {
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST);
    }
    else {
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Substitute the `IllegalArgumentException` with the exception of interest, and of course the `SC_BAD_REQUEST` (400) with the status code of interest.

Either way, this won't consult `<error-page><exception-type>` anymore and will thus end up in below error page:

```xml
<error-page>
    <status-code>400</status-code>
    </location>/WEB-INF/errorpages/400.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```