# Bind different status code to HttpServletResponse in the servlet that handles uncaught exceptions

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

in my project I've defined a few types of exceptions that are supposed to be mapped to respective response status code

```java
// map to status code 400
public class BadRequest400Exception extends RuntimeException {}

// map to status code 401
public class Unauthorized401Exception extends RuntimeException {}

// map to status code 404
public class NotFound404Exception extends RuntimeException {}
```

Please note that I do not want to catch these exceptions inside original servlets where they are thrown. That's why I make them unchecked. In other words, I don't want to have something like this

```java
public class BusinessLogicServlet extends HttpServlet {
  
  @Override
  protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
      throws ServletException, IOException {
     try {
         // some business logic
         throw new Unauthorized401Exception();
     } catch (Exception e) {
         resp.sendError(401, "...");
     }
  }
```

which actually defeats my original purpose of processing these runtime exceptions all together in a central place. For that, I define a dedicated servlet for handling all uncaught exception thrown. It will forward the request to the appropriate error page based on type of exception

web.xml:

```xml
<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.Exception</exception-type>
    <location>/WEB-INF/exception</location>
</error-page>

<!-- ... -->

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ExceptionCentralProcessingServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>foo.bar.baz.ExceptionCentralProcessingServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ExceptionCentralProcessingServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/WEB-INF/exception</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

ExceptionCentralProcessingServlet:

```java
public class ExceptionCentralProcessingServlet extends HttpServlet {

  @Override
  protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
      throws ServletException, IOException {
     
     Throwable throwable = (Throwable) request.getAttribute(RequestDispatcher.ERROR_EXCEPTION);

     if (throwable instanceof BadRequest400Exception) {
        // I want to change status code from 500 to 400 in this case
        // which is not working
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST);
        // also not working
        // response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST);
        request
              .getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/views/error-pages/error-page-400.jsp")
              .forward(request, response);
        return;
     }
     
     if (throwable instanceof NotFound404Exception) {
        // I want to change status code from 500 to 404 in this case
        // which is not working
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND);
        // also not working
        // response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND);
        request
              .getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/views/error-pages/error-page-404.jsp")
              .forward(request, response);
        return;
     }
  }
}
```

When I test it, this seems to be partially working. When BadRequest400Exception is thrown from a servlet, the request is forwarded to error-page-400.jsp. However, the response status code is still `500`, despite that I've explicitly change it to 400 via `response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST);`. According to [Change response code in javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31514732), this is supposed to work but it actually doesn't work out.
I also try the other method `sendError`: `response.sendError(400)` but this is also not working.

I want to know how to change the http status code (default seems to be 500) to other values in the servlet declared for `<exception-type>` that processes uncaught exception thrown from other servlets.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to catch and handle exceptions in a centralized place outside of your main servlet, a simpler approach may be to use a [filter](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/filters.html). Filters are able to change the response status code.

A very basic example would look something like:

```
public class ExceptionFilter implements Filter {
    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {
        // nothing to do
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        // nothing to do
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) {
        try {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        } catch BadRequest400Exception e) {
            // however you want to handle this exception
        } catch Unauthorized401Exception e) {
            // however you want to handle this exception
        }
        // etc...
    }
}
```

Note that you would also need to set up a corresponding `filter-mapping` in your `web.xml`.

In this example, the filter simply "wraps" the servlet request/response. Any uncaught exception that is thrown out of your servlet could be caught with the try/catch in the filter, such as to set a response status code, forward to a JSP, write to a log, etc.

Comment: Thanks, this looks like a good solution and I'll give it a try. If I am going to set up this filter in my app, does it need to the first one in the chain, so it actually wraps every other filter and servlet?

Comment: @torez233 Yes, if you need it to cover everything, it should be first so that everything passes through it.